# Chrome extension, play sound in background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to play a sound from a Chrome Extension, but I read that Content Scripts cannot play sounds.  So I put this code in my background script:

```
var audio = new Audio("alert.ogg");
audio.play();
```

but still no sound.  From the Console of the _generated_backgound_page.html  I was able to inspect the Network tab and see that the sound file is loaded successfully, but I hear nothing.

Also, in another HTML page, I could load another Javascript, which has the above code, and it works (I can hear the sound.)

The fact that it is in the background script seems to have made it fail.  Also, note that I do not have a background PAGE associated with the background SCRIPT.  Does that matter？

edit:  **problem solved**.  The above code works but I forgot to listen to the right sound output channel.

Comment: It was just a stupid mistake... my audio output got changed to another sound device.  Maybe I should delete question?

Comment: You should mark a question as "invalid" somehow.

Comment: But there is no way to mark it.

Comment: Just edit your question: write that it is invalid and write how you solved it. Like mine one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318983/webrtc-scalable-broadcasting

Comment: You should do one of the following: 1) answer your own question and mark that as accepted, 2) delete the question altogether, if you feel it doesn't help others.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the background page with javascript. I think the sound must be in a html page to be loaded and played.

This should work:

```
document.write('<audio id="player" src="data:audio/wav;base64,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" >');
document.getElementById('player').play();
```

I used a base64 audio file but you can use a normal file too.

Comment: It gives error `
play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`.