# Live streaming webcam with Janus

Tags: webrtc, janus

I am trying to live stream video and audio from a user's webcam, with WebRTC. I cannot figure out how to do it with Janus Webrtc gateway, so that a person would stream webcam, and others can view it on another webpage.

I have installed Janus and I am able to connect with the Janus server with a browser. I attach the session to the streaming plugin, and then I create an offer with `createOffer`. The `onlocalstream` function is called, and I set the `srcObject` of my video element.

**The broadcaster**
I am able to attach the session to the streaming plugin like this:

```
janus.attach({
   plugin: "janus.plugin.streaming",    
    [...]
```

..then in the success handler I create an offer like this:

```
success: function(pluginHandle) {
    streaming = pluginHandle;
    var body = { "audio": { deviceId: { exact: audioSelect.value }},"video": { deviceId: { exact: videoSelect.value }} };
    streaming.createOffer({
        media: {
            audioSend: true,
            videoSend: true,
            audioRecv: false,
            videoRecv: false,
            audio: { deviceId: { exact: audioSelect.value }},
            video: { deviceId: { exact: videoSelect.value }}
       },
       success: function(jsep) {
           console.log("jsep = " + jsep);
           streaming.send({"message": body, "jsep": jsep});
       },
       error: function(error) { 
           console.log("error creating offer: " + error); 
       }
    });
},
```

**The viewer**
On the viewer's page I attach to the streaming plugin as well, and here I do not really know what to do. Do I create an offer with `createOffer`, or `createAnswer`?

And is the streaming plugin the correct plugin for what I want?

I do see an error on the Janus server when the broadcaster connects:
`[ERR] [plugins/janus_streaming.c:janus_streaming_handle_message:3614] Missing mandatory element (request)`

I want a user to stream webcam, and other users would see it (one-to-many broadcast). I have read this thread, and the user nschoe said that it is possible with Janus: 
[WebRTC - scalable live stream broadcasting / multicasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318983/webrtc-scalable-live-stream-broadcasting-multicasting/57824620)

Comment: how you solved the problem?

Comment: I'm also trying to do this

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced this issue with a sample implementation using Python. Please try it by adding

```
media:{
    request:"request type"
    ....
}
Where "request type" can be list, info, create, destroy, recording, edit, enable and disable
```

You can get more information at its [Streaming API documentation](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/streaming.html)